# Margaritas three, four, and nine

Tags: dialogue, friends

In the uncut version of the *Friends* episode The One At the Beach (Season 3, Episode 25) there's the following scene:

> Phoebe: So, you’re all bored?
>
> Chandler: Yes!
>
> Phoebe: All right, I’m gonna close my eyes and point to someone, and you, whoever I point has to come up with something fun for us to do, and we have to do it.
>
> (They do so, and Phoebe gets in the middle, closes her eyes, and starts spinning in a circle. She stops at Chandler)
>
> Chandler: Okay, umm, we all have to play strip poker.
>
> Monica: Chandler! Why, all of a sudden, do you wanna play strip poker?
>
> **Chandler: I think because of margaritas three, four, and nine.**

What does Chandler mean by what he said? Why 3, 4 and 9?

Comment: You might want to take a look at some of the formatting improvements people did on various of your previous questions. For more information you can also consult the [help center](http://movies.stackexchange.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Sorry I am having difficulties on grasping the right formatting, but I am working on it.

Comment: My take on it? 'Because of the 9 margaritas' isn't funny enough, but also specifying exactly *which* margaritas made him the right kind of drunk to suggest it *is*.

Comment: @Walt Any reservations to fleshing that out into an answer? It's exactly the bit that the existing answers are missing.

Answer (score 4):

I think he is just trying to get the point across that he is very drunk and isn't exactly sure how many margaritas he has had and now would be a good time to have a game of strip poker. Strip poker is usually the kinda game you would play when you are drunk.

Comment: Are those numbers absolutely random? Because he looked like he hand-picked them!

Comment: imagine you're sober. You observe a friend drink 2 drinks and still be reasonably sensible. Then they drink 3 more - margaritas 3, 4, and *5*. Now they aren't making any sense at all and think strip poker would be smart. He's trying to explain this, but he's so drunk he gets *the number after 3, 4, ...* wrong. That drunk.

Comment: Or maybe he's trying to say that 3 and 4 are the start of the drunkness, and 9 did complete it totally.